# Better git directory arrangement

Tags: git

I currently finished creating my web application and now, im trying to implement a mobile application using React native. 
This might be a stupid question but should I create a new project for my react native project or should I create a new directory inside my original web project in github?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

## Create a seperate repository

The web app does not need the mobile app and the mobile app does not need the web app(at least not as a dependency, it may communicate over e.g. an API).

The web app is not part of the mobile app and the mobile app is not part of the web app.

Therefore, I recommend you to create seperate directories and creating a git repository for each of the apps. You may want to use the same organisation/user account for the repositories and (maybe) link the apps in e.g. the `README`.

You can also have a directory(and repository) with both projects as subdirectories but you have to navigate to through it every time, a community contributor would need to clone everything, etc.